# How to change to Right-to-Left language in keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I know that there is a key in info.plist: PrefersRightToLeft which specifies if keyboard's primary language is a right to left language. But I can't set it to YES because my keyboard has multiple languages.

Now I want to add Arabic (right-to-left).

How can I change the typing direction to right-to-left at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
[textField setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft forRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] toPosition:[textField endOfDocument]]];
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: Thanks but a keyboard doesn't have access to the current textField. Any other way?

Comment: In my case i can access my current textfield

Comment: "textField" is you currenttextField